# LocalStorage - Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have issue that local storage saves first dropdown menu choice but not second and third one. What should be edited or added in HTML and JS for multiple.

```js
var init = function (){
  //an ugly warning to users without localStorage support
  if(!window.localStorage){
    $('body').prepend('Sorry, you browser does not support local storage');
    return false;
  }
  var sel = $('select'),
      but = $('button');
  
  var clearSelected = function(){
      sel.find(':selected').prop('selected', false);
  }
  
  if(localStorage.getItem('pref')){
    var pref = localStorage.getItem('pref');
    clearSelected();
    //set the selected state to true on the option localStorage remembers
    sel.find('#' + pref).prop('selected', true);
  }

  var setPreference = function(){
    //remember the ID of the option the user selected
    localStorage.setItem('pref', sel.find(':selected').attr('id'));
  };
  
  var reset = function(){
    clearSelected();
    localStorage.setItem('pref', undefined);
  }
  
  sel.on('change', setPreference);
  but.on('click', reset);
};
$(document).ready(init);
```

```html
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="2.js"></script>
    </head>
<select>
  <option selected></option>
  <option id="opt1">1</option>
  <option id="opt2">2</option>
  <option id="opt3">3</option>
  <option id="opt4">4</option>
</select>
<br></br>
<select>
  <option selected></option>
  <option id="opt5">5</option>
  <option id="opt6">6</option>
  <option id="opt7">7</option>
  <option id="opt8">8</option>
</select>
```

Comment: store the selection in an stringified array instead. `localStorage.items = JSON.stringify([...JSON.parse(localStorage.items), newItem])`

Comment: @TheFool Can you be kind and please provide edited example.

Answer (score 0):

`var sel = $('select'),` selects both the dropdowns.

add id's to the dropdowns

```html
<select id="first">
```

change `setPreference` to this

```js
var setPreference = function () {
  //remember the ID of the option the user selected
  localStorage.setItem('pref', this.value);
};
```

and adjust the localstorage retrieving logic accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I made the changes however now they both don't save. I apologize for my level of knowledge but it's my first time and simply need it for work.

```js
var init = function (){
  //an ugly warning to users without localStorage support
  if(!window.localStorage){
    $('body').prepend('Sorry, you browser does not support local storage');
    return false;
  }
  var sel = $('select'),
      but = $('button');
  
  var clearSelected = function(){
      sel.find(':selected').prop('selected', false);
  }
  
  if(localStorage.getItem('pref')){
    var pref = localStorage.getItem('pref');
    clearSelected();
    //set the selected state to true on the option localStorage remembers
    sel.find('#' + pref).prop('selected', true);
  }

  var setPreference = function () {
  //remember the ID of the option the user selected
  localStorage.setItem('pref', this.value);
};
  
  var reset = function(){
    clearSelected();
    localStorage.setItem('pref', undefined);
  }
  
  sel.on('change', setPreference);
  but.on('click', reset);
};
$(document).ready(init);
```

```html
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="2.js"></script>
    </head>
<select id="first">
  <option id="opt1">1</option>
  <option id="opt2">2</option>
  <option id="opt3">3</option>
  <option id="opt4">4</option>
</select>
<br></br>
<select id="second">
  <option id="opt5">5</option>
  <option id="opt6">6</option>
  <option id="opt7">7</option>
  <option id="opt8">8</option>
</select>
<br></br>
```